# Can I select a specific data center in Japan for Watson Knowledge Catalog?

Tags: watson-knowledge-catalog

1. Can I select a specific data center in Japan to deploy to? Can I specifically select TOK4? Japan has three datacenters: TOK02, 04, 05
2. If the customer can not select, can I know which data center WKC deploy to? : TOK02, 04, 05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watson Knowledge Catalog is deployed in the Tokyo MZR that spans the three data centers.  You cannot select a specific data center.

To access WKC deployed in Tokyo data center, use the following link:

https://jp-tok.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com​